# looking to print out the factorial answer for this question. i.e 5*4*3*2*1= 120

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, pycharm, factorial

```
    number = int(input("Please enter a number:"))

    result = 1

    for i in range(number, 0, -1):
        result = result * i
    print("factorial of", number, "equals", result)
```

1. I want to print the full factorial expression out at the end. i.e 
   6*5*4*3*2*1=720

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
expression = '*'.join(map(str, range(6,0,-1)))
# '6*5*4*3*2*1'
```

It may require some explanations:

- map(str, ...) transforms your list of integers into a list of str
- '*'.join puts a multiplication sign between all these numbers